# Show individual file in file upload in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

hello please any one help me i am trying to upload file in prime-faces file upload event with advance mode and auto true, but my file will be save when i click on save button auto true only will save it in my Files list, but with auto true i am unable to show files to user which he/she chosen.

Here is the image [image]

here is xhtml:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                            <p:dataTable id="flName" var="obj" value="#{empRegManagedBean.allRequiredDocuments}"
                                                         paginatorPosition="bottom" rowIndexVar="row" reflow="true" rows="10"
                                                         paginator="true">
                                                <p:column  headerText="S#" style="width:36px">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{row+1}"/>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="File Name" style="width: 30%">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{obj.documentTitle}" />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Required " style="width: 10%">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{obj.required eq true? 'YES' : 'NO'  }" />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Submitted" style="width: 10%" rendered="#{empRegManagedBean.employeeObj.employeeId > 0}">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{obj.submitted eq true? 'YES' : 'NO'  }"/>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Upload " style="width: 20%">
                                                    <p:fileUpload   
                                                        fileUploadListener="#{empRegManagedBean.fileUpload}"    
                                                        multiple="false" auto="true"  update="flName" sizeLimit="1000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(docx|jpe?g|png|pdf|xlsx|txt)$/" >
                                                        <f:attribute name="docID" value="#{obj.documentId}" />
                                                        <f:attribute name="doctitl" value="#{obj.showtitle}" />

                                                    </p:fileUpload>

                                                </p:column>

                                                <p:column headerText="Download" style="width: 30%" rendered="#{empRegManagedBean.employeeObj.employeeId > 0}">

                                                    <h:outputLink rendered="#{obj.documentTitle ne null}"  value="../../Upload_companyLogo/#{obj.documentTitle}">
                                                        <img src=""  alt="#{obj.documentTitle}" align="top"/>

                                                    </h:outputLink>
                                                </p:column>




                                            </p:dataTable>
                                        </h:form>
```

Following is managed Bean:

```
     public void fileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
 event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("docID");
    this.globalevents.add(event);
    System.out.println("Event " + event.getFile().getFileName());
    try {


        count++;
        System.out.println("Change properties occures" + event);
        String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRealPath("/");
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String name = fmt.format(new Date()) + "_" + event.getFile().getFileName();

        if (!(event.getFile().getFileName().contains(this.employeeObj.getEmployeeCode()))) {
            documentFileType = this.employeeObj.getEmployeeCode() + "_" + count + "_" + event.getFile().getFileName();
            docID = (Integer) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("docID");
            showTitle = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("doctitl");
            System.out.println("Document Id : " + docID);
            System.out.println("showTitle : " + showTitle);
        }

        if (event.getFile().getFileName() != null) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }

        tempPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("fileUplodDirectory");
        docsFiles = new File(tempPath + documentFileType);
        HRMFile f = new HRMFile();
        f.setDocFile(docsFiles);
        f.setEvent(event);
        f.setFileName(docsFiles.getName());
        f.setDocumentId(docID);
        f.setPath(tempPath);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        f.setUploadedDateTime(c.getTime());
        f.setVtmsTypeCode(1);
        f.setType(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        System.out.println(tempPath);
        System.out.println(tempPath);
        if (attachedFiles == null) {
            attachedFiles = new ArrayList();
        }
        attachedFiles.add(f);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmpRegisterManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is **no** advanced mode in your upload. And **don't** upload files in your expanded webapp... Bad design...

Comment: its in advance mode but when you set auto true, its hide advance mode

Comment: But sir for my web it is most important part please suggest me the way

Comment: @Kukeltje sir is there any way to show my chosen files name in that data table one by one

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml has both `auto="true"` and `mode="advanced"`, yours does not. Yours has a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and the showcase has not

Comment: primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml sir how can i achieve that my task, my requirement is that user can select individual file it should be shown in that data table, because i needed document ID to so please guide me

Comment: Start by reading my previous comments and acting on them

Comment: sir i used it but not get result as i needed

Comment: What you tried is not reflected in the code in your question. And try to make a [mcve] so others van more easily der what the actual behaviour is when trying to replicatie. And post version info of PF and version and impact of your JSF libs

Comment: my requirement is that  one by one select file and save it in file upload event when user click on  save button all file should be save in database on the base of employee id

Comment: @Kukeltje  and also with document id which is in document table so please suggest me best way to do it

Comment: Your requirements is clear, you States that multiple Times. But as long as you are not updating the Q as commented before (=my suggestions), I see no incentive to investigate more... Cheers